# Why bootstrap form helper language picker making no effects, while pushing a tags in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a language bar with the jQuery bootstrap plugin, but it seems there is no option to append any action to anchor tags in drop down menu at all. They are just un-clickable.

Initialization of plugin:

```
<div class="bfh-selectbox bfh-languages" data-language="pl_PL" data-available="en_US,pl_PL" data-flags="true" data-blank="false">
    <input type="hidden" value="">
    <a class="bfh-selectbox-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="bfh-selectbox" href="#">
        <span class="bfh-selectbox-option input-medium" data-option=""></span>
        <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <div class="bfh-selectbox-options">
        <div role="listbox">
            <ul role="option">
                <li>
                    <a href="/index.php?lang=pl_PL" data-option="pl_PL">
                        <i class="glyphicon bfh-flag-PL"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="/index.php?lang=en_US" data-option="en_US">
                        <i class="glyphicon bfh-flag-US"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Commenting or uncommenting doesn't make any difference.

### Another possibly related issue:

When I'm stretching out my web page, with the container overflowing the language bar completely,  it becomes completely un-clickable. I don't want to change this plugin on something else in case someone will offer.
The address of the website is [here](http://vasyldemianiuk.com).

Comment: Great site man. But I don't seem to understand where your so called `dropdown` is.

Comment: In the top-right corner.